# Assigning a value to a variable in XSLT and using that value later in the same XSLT document

Tags: xslt

I have this sample xml;

```
<rows>
  <row index="1">
    <column index="2">Application,xms,xmx,gc,vm1,vm2,,,,</column>
   </row>
</rows>
```

I see how to get the application value and assign it to a variable with that name:

```
<xsl:variable name="ApplicationName" select="substring-before(., &quot;,&quot;)" />
```

But I dont see how to use that variable to to get the xms value.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)? If so, you could make use of the `tokenize` function, to split the string by commas. This would be more useful as it would make it easier to access all the other parts of the string too.

Answer (score 1):

Combine `substring-before` with `substring-after`, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="ApplicationName" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,','), ',')" />
```

which output should be `xms`(the second item).

`substring-after(.,',')` retrieves the string after the first `,`:

```
xms,xmx,gc,vm1,vm2,,,,
```

and `substring-before(...,',')` retrieves the part before the first `,` of the above string which is

```
xms
```